# Can we do logical AND operation of an array with array element?

Tags: python, c, arrays

Hello Friend,
I am novice in Python.
I saw an instruction in Python programming today in this link
http://www.learnpython.org/page/Conditions
There in question he wants to carryout logical AND operation with array and array element.
I tried the same in C.
But C threw an error.
How can we do it?
And how the AND operation will happen here?

```
first_array = [3, 4, 5]
if first_array and first_array[0] == 1:
   print "5"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in c

```
int first_array[] = { 3,4,5};
if ( (first_array != null) && (first_array[0] == 3 )) 
{
    printf("5");
}
```

Comment: Thanks A lot for making me understand

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking but I'll take a shot at giving you some options:

The code you've written checks to see whether `first_array` is empty or not, and also whether the first element is 0. This is actually decent practice because `first_array[0]` will raise an exception if `first_array` is empty. This construction avoids this error because the second condition won't be evauluated unless the first is true (that`s how`and` works in Python).

If you want to check whether *all* or *any* items in the list are truthy (non-zero, if they're numbers), you can use Python's `all()` or `any()` function.

```
if any(first_array) and first_array[0] == 1:
    # etc
```

If you want to check whether all (or any) items in the list have a particular value, you can use a generator expression with `any`/`all`:

```
if any(element == 3 for element in first_array) and first_array[0] == 1:
    # and so on
```

However, the preferred way to check whether a list contains a particular value is not a construction like the above, but the much simpler `in`:

```
if 3 in first_array and first_array[0] == 1:
    # action
```

Comment: I would just like to note your second example simplifies down to `if first_array[0] == 1:` - if the latter segment is true, the former always will be.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Mainly kept the second condition in to show the use of `and`. (Of course I'd still recommend testing the list itself before accessing element 0 if there's any possibility it will be empty.)

Answer (score 0):

first of all "and" in python is && in C. second, python implements lists not array, third i don't quite your question: is python throwing an exception for the above code? If so then perhaps you have python 3 installed in witch case it should go like

```
 print("5")
```

Otherwise , if the question is C related then please change the question

Comment: Python is not showing the error. C was showing error because I made logical AND.

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
if first_array and first_array[0] == 1:
```

is true iff the both sub-expressions `first_array` and `first_array[0] == 1` are true.

A list is true iff it contains elements, the second one is trivial.